# OpenVPN Client doesn't connect to my own server, but receives packets according to tcpdump

Tags: networking, centos, ssl, openvpn

My problem is that I cant connect to my OpenVPN Server. I always get a "TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)" error. Running tcpdump while trying to connect on port 1194 on my server showed 4 packets from my PC.

My server.conf in /etc/openvpn/server:

```
# OpenVPN Port, Protocol, and the Tun
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

#listen
local *my DNS*

# OpenVPN Server Certificate - CA, server key and certificate
ca /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server/*cert*.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server/*key*.key

#DH and CRL key
dh /etc/openvpn/server/dh.pem
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/server/crl.pem

# Network Configuration - Internal network
# Redirect all Connection through OpenVPN Server
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"

# Using the DNS from https://dns.watch
push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.69.80"
push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.70.40"

#Enable multiple clients to connect with the same certificate key
duplicate-cn

# TLS Security
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-version-min 1.0
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA256
auth SHA512
auth-nocache

# Other Configuration
keepalive 20 60
persist-key
persist-tun
compress lz4
daemon
user nobody
group nobody


# OpenVPN Log
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 4
```

my client.ovpn on my Windows client:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp

remote *my DNS* 1194

ca "c:\\Users\\*Username*\\Documents\\OpenVPNFiles\\Client1\\client\\ca.crt"
cert "c:\\Users\\*Username*\\Documents\\OpenVPNFiles\\Client1\\client\\*cert*.crt"
key "c:\\Users\\*Username*\\Documents\\OpenVPNFiles\\Client1\\client\\*key*.key"

cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
auth-nocache
tls-version-min 1.0
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA256
remote-cert-tls server

resolv-retry infinite
compress lz4
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
verb 4
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: First things first, did you look in the Log ? /var/log/openvpn.log ? any error ? messages ?

Comment: in case you're not sure it listen to the right interface just remove the ```local *my DNS*``` line, and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have fixed it myself. The problem was that the server..conf file was in /etc/oopnvpn/server instead of /etc/openvpn.